# Assign new coordinates to Xarray.Dataset data variables and drop old coordinates

Tags: python-xarray

I have the following dataset

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "temperature_c": (
            ("lat", "lon"),
            20 * np.random.rand(4).reshape(2, 2)
        )
    },
    coords={"lat": [10, 20], "lon": [150, 160]},
)
```

I want to add a new coordinate called `custom_idx`. I do this by running

```
ds.set_coords(("custom_idx"))
```

How do I make `custom_idx` the *only* coordinate of `temperature_c`?

Comment: Can you give precisions on `custom_idx` ? `temperature_c` is a 2D DataArray, why would you need a single coordinate to describe it ? I suspect your `custom_idx` to be [[0, 1], [2, 3]], is it correct ?

Comment: yes, you'r right about that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "condense" the existing 2 dimensions into a single dimension, you need to stack the Dataset. Afterwards, you can use `assign_coords` to set coordinates for the new index:

```
custom_idx_values = list("ABCD")
result = (
    ds.stack(custom_idx=["lat", "lon"])
    .drop_vars(["lon", "lat", "custom_idx"])
    .assign_coords(custom_idx=custom_idx_values)
)
print(result)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:        (custom_idx: 4)
Coordinates:
  * custom_idx     (custom_idx) <U1 'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'
Data variables:
    temperature_c  (custom_idx) float64 4.736 0.2115 15.41 17.19
```